# Safe to call underlying java method on String in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion

Adobe ColdFusion is built on Java.  Almost all simple variables in CFML/CFSCRIPT are `java.lang.String` until the operation needs it to be of a certain type.

I've always want to use `startsWith()` in `String` instead of the more bulky CFML variant.

```
left(str,4) EQ "test"
```

However, what's the general consensus of using underlying Java method in ColdFusion?

Would this be any safer to `javacast()` the var first?

```
javacast("String",x).startsWith("test");
```

What if the CF engine is not built on top of Java?

Thanks

Comment: Adobe ColdFusion since 6 and Railo are built on Java. BlueDragon has both a java and a .net version.

Comment: @JamesMohler yes, but from my experience, just calling `"someString".someJavaStringMethod()` would fail *sometimes* in production.  Therefore I've stopped using it.

Comment: I would image that CF Trim() coerces the variable to being a string, where as calling the Java function does not.

Comment: @JamesMohler The thing is, the underlying object might not be a String object at all times.  It could be a Date or something else in Java, although it behaves like a string in CF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with Adobe ColdFusion and other CFML engines that are built on Java. It's actually simpler than you thought.

```
<cfset str = "hello what's up" />
#str.startsWith("hello")# <!--- returns "YES" --->
<cfif str.startsWith("h")>
  This text will be output
</cfif>

#str.startsWith("goodbye")# <!--- returns "NO" --->
<cfif str.startsWith("g")>
  This text will NOT be output
</cfif>
```

This is possible because CFML strings in ColdFusion are the same as Java strings. You can use any native string method [(Java.lang.String)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) on a CFML string.

If you haven't guessed, this also works with CFML arrays (some kind of list, probably a java.util.Vector) and structs (probably a java.util.Map). Experiment with data types and the cfdump tag, you will find a lot of secrets.

One word of warning, this is **not** standard CFML, so if your underlying engine changes, including just upgrading to a new version, there are no guarantees that it will still work.

That said, string.startsWith() is native to Java as well as .NET, so this will also work if your CFML engine is BlueDragon.NET. The only CFML engines it will not work on are ColdFusion 5 and previous.

Is it safe to use? I would say yes. As long as CFML engines run on Java or .NET, it's perfectly safe. It's undocumented, but easy to understand, so I would say use it freely.

Comment: I guess the question is.. How Safe?

Comment: I updated my response, last 3 paragraphs, to talk about if it's safe and my opinion if you should use it. If that doesn't answer it, please clarify your question.

Comment: As Nathan says, it is all undocumented. So if you are not comfortable with the risk factor, using the documented javacast() function may be preferable.  Though having said that, String's are a core part of both java and C#. So IMO, using the undocumented string.startsWith() would be far safer than depending on arrays being Vectors, for example. That I _could_ see changing in the near future.

Comment: I have used `mystring.trim()` .

Comment: While it's "safe" (when using a "string"0, it's also appears to be less performant than using left(), right() and trim().

Answer (score 3):

I have found that using built in cf functions in most cases is faster than leveraging their java counterparts, mainly as it costs so much in cf wrapping the java methods.

If you are using .startsWith(), remember it's case sensitive, whereas cf's eq isn't.
Same goes for most of the other java String methods - .endsWith(), .contains() etc.

Unless you can bundle large sets of functionality as roll your own java util classes, mixing cf and java calls seems slow. If you are in some java code, and you have a string, and you call its startsWith() method, it just executes. Done. In cf code, you have to javaCast or blindly hope the variable is in the correct data type, which is risky with things like entirely numeric strings, and when you call a .startsWith(), there is a bunch of cf code that runs before it even gets down to the java level, which is where the slowness lives. Eg. Cf's dynamic arguments means that it has to check if there is a method on the supplied object with that many args, and of those data types (or compatible types). There is just a whole bunch of code that unavoidably runs, bridging the two languages.

But don't trust our experiences, benchmark for yourselves. eg.

```
<cfscript>
var sys = createObject( 'java', 'java.lang.System' );
var timer = sys.nanoTime();
    // run some code here
timer = sys.nanoTime() - timer;
writeDump( var: timer );
</cfscript>
```

If you are using the Adobe cf engine, watch out of entirely numeric strings, they bounce between java Doubles and Strings, and don't get me started with serializeJSON()...